Ros2 Control Hexapod Robot
I have been struggling for months now to try and port Kevin Ochs' hexapod_ros repository to ROS2. I have struggled immensely to get things working and continuously run into bugs. I was wondering if anyone knows of a robust hexapod codebase based on ROS2 that I can use, the idea is to eventually add dynamic gait to the robot so that it can walk on uneven surfaces, but for now I just really need a codebase that I can use for foundational control of the robot.
I was really hoping to use Kevin Ochs' code because it seems to have been used in multiple scenarios and thus is more robust thatnn a codebase built from scratch, but if there are no other options. I will definitely create some basic code to operate the robot.
Thanks.
